# Virtualbox Blank USB Filter - Now Mouse and KB doesnt work

Tags: server, virtualbox

Experimenting with USB filters, I created a blank filter and now both the mouse and KB don't work for both the guest and the host.

Is there any way I can regain control without rebooting the server?

(Ubuntu Server 12.04)

Comment: Do you have ssh on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the virtual machine settings on the command-line, via [VBoxManage usbfilter add/modify/remove](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp20402240).